# Not able to add nuget packages to vnext project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I've created a asp.net 5 project and am trying to add a reference to an older package from NuGet (Mysql.Data). From what I've read, I should be able to do this to add pre-vnext packages:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net45": {
            "dependencies": {
            "MySql.Data": "6.9.4"
            }
        },
        "aspnet50": { },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22416"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But all that happens is I get a reference to it in the project browser but there is a yellow triangle next to it. I have seen other similar questions on here but they all suggest the above, but I'm not sure why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the MySQL library is not supported in aspnetcore5, you can remove the aspnetcore50 JSON node and that will get rid of the warning. Not all libraries are supported in core. See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269766/reference-local-project-in-net-vnext-when-a-nuget-package-of-the-same-name-is-p/28279010#28279010)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Son_of_Sam said, you need to put this in the dependencies section at the top.

Comment: Shame I can't accept two answers - this helped me realise that I was wrong to create a net45 node - so thanks!