# Reference local project in .net vNext when a nuget package of the same name is published

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a package with the new vNext project type in VS 2015.

I would like to reference a project in the same solution (which isn't vNext) but its trying to find a nuget package for that project rather than directly referencing it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0.0-beta2"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "React": "" //it cant find a package for this even though I have a project named this in my solution
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project structure:

```
Solution Folder
 - src 
   - global.json {"sources": [""]} 
   - React (project folder)
   - My Library (project folder)
 - bin
   - Debug
     - React
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to actually create a nuGet package for the local assembly. vNext

Comment: @dbugger So you cant reference a local project without turning  it into a nuget package? Surely that isn't the case?

Comment: I thought you were talking about creating a package, but from some reading it does seem the nuGet approach is favored.

Comment: http://tomlane.me/2014/11/asp-net-vnext-local-references/

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2015 CTP5 then it will allow you to add reference of project in same solution even if it is not vnext type.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:** You need to add a `net45` configuration to your `project.json` where you can then add the `React` dependency (assuming its a `net45` binary).

*NOTE:* I've updated the *Short Answer* to reflect new information added to the question. The long answer below is purely informational.

**Info on Dependency Resolution:**
An important thing to note is that in vNext (ASP.NET 5) Visual Studio is not necessary. Therefore we can't think of things in terms of "it's in my solution" since that's a Visual Studio concept and everything is designed to work outside of Visual Studio.

So, lets first talk about what can be referenced from a project in vNext:

1. A package.
2. Source code (literally .cs files) as long as there's a project.json.
3. A dll.

*I think that's everything but I could be forgetting.*

Now the beauty here is that their references are all interchangeable. Meaning your addition of the dependency `"React": ""` can reference a dll, package, or source code (source code has the highest priority if there's conflicts). Note that leaving the version as `""` essentially means "1.0" OR source code.

Now after reading this far you're probably thinking, o.k. cool I just wrote this issue saying I have a conflict, why aren't my dependencies resolving correctly? So first off there are two ways to provide locations for valid Source Code/projects that you can add a dependency to.

1. Implied: Tries its best to finds the code around you automagically
2. Specified: Provide a global.json to indicate where to look for source code.

90% of the time you should be using #2 where #1 you should be using purely for demos :) if you can avoid it.

**Where does a global.json go?** In a parents folder.
**What's in a global.json?** All you need is valid json, it can look something like this:

```
{
    "sources": ["src", "test"]
}
```

With this global.json, all source code in the `src` and `test` folder will be discovered.

Aka:

```
- global.json
- /src
-> A.cs
- /test
-> B.cs
```

Examples of this type of folder structure: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was very helpful, I understand much more about how the global.json works. However I still cant get my references to work. I think it may be something to do with the bin folder being in a weird place. Ive added the folder structure to my question, and tried pointing sources to the bin folders but it didnt seem to work (eg ../bin/debug for example) any ideas?

Comment: So one thing to note is that `React` hopefully is a net45 equivalent project and therefore will only be avilable in a net45 node in your project.json. Now seeing your project structure you shouldn't need a global.json (it will automagically find your project). Updating answer to reflect new details.

Answer (score 2):

If you using VS2015 CTP there is an option to create the nuget package automatically, by checking the produce outputs on build in the project property/build section. The nuget package will be create in the artifact folder of the solution you will need to manually push those your nuget server.

Regarding what project you can add as reference is a little bit tricky. This is what I did. I created 5 projects 2 using vs2013 and 3 using vs2015 the last one is a web project to test project reference.

Only C# project are allow as reference, VB projects for now are not supported. Assuming that you have a class library that was create on 2013 you can add those to your VS2015 solution without an upgrade (so far) then you can add those as reference  to others vNext projects  but will not work aspnet5core.

[image: VNExt Project Reference]
[image: Nuget Packages Creates]
[image: VS2015 Options to create nuget packages]